# Unexpected Ruby behavior when instantiating two instances on one line

Tags: ruby, testing, instance

I created a class that generates a different name for each instance, but a test fails unexpectedly when instantiating two instances in one statement.

Here is the class.

```
class Robot
  attr_accessor :name
  @@current_name = 'AA000'
  def initialize
    @name = @@current_name
    @@current_name.next!
  end
end
```

Here the class behaves as expected

```
irb(main):009:0> Robot.new.name
=> "AA001"
irb(main):010:0> Robot.new.name
=> "AA002"
```

Here is the unexpected behavior, I was expecting `false`. This code is in a test on an exercise I am trying to get passing, so I can't change the test.

```
irb(main):011:0> Robot.new.name == Robot.new.name
=> true
```

Checking the `object_id` reveals that two different instances are being created.

```
irb(main):012:0> Robot.new.object_id == Robot.new.object_id
=> false
```

Why is Ruby doing this, what should I do to fix it & assuming there is a term for this, what could I have typed into search to find answered questions about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See if this helps:

```
class Robot
  attr_accessor :name

  @@current_name = 'AA000'

  def initialize
    @name = @@current_name
    @@current_name.next!
  end
end

x = Robot.new 
puts x.name
y = Robot.new
puts y.name

puts x.name == y.name
puts x.name
puts y.name

--output:--
AA001
AA002
true
AA002
AA002
```

> Why is Ruby doing this

Because each instance's `@name` variable refers to the same String as the variable `@@current_name`, and you keep changing that String with the `!` method.

> what should I do to fix it

```
class Robot
  attr_accessor :name

  @@current_name = 'AA000'

  def initialize
    @name = @@current_name.dup
    @@current_name.next!
  end
end


x = Robot.new 
puts x.name
y = Robot.new
puts y.name

p x.name == y.name
p x.name
p y.name

--output:--
AA000
AA001
false
AA000
AA001
```

Although, I and many other people will warn you NEVER to use `@@variables` in your code.

**Ruby assignment operator**:

```
1. x = “hello”:

x  ------> “hello”


2. y = x:

x  ------> “hello”  
              ^
              |
y  -----------+


3.  y << “ world”:


x  ------> “hello world”  
              ^  ^
              |  ^
y  -----------+  ^
   >     >     >
```

It matters not that x and y's names may be spelled `@name` and `@@current_name`.

Here is another code example:

```
x = "hello"
y = x 
y << " world" 

puts x, y

--output:--
hello world
hello world


x.next!
puts x, y

--output:--
hello worle
hello worle
```

Here is an example with `immutable types`:

```
1. x = 10:

x  ------> 10


2. y = x:

x  ---------> 10  
              ^
              |
y  -----------+


3.  y += 1 
    => y = y + 1
    => y = 10 + 1
    And 10 + 1 creates the new Integer object 11 and assigns it to y:


x  ------> 10  

y  ------> 11
```

The expression `10 + 1` does NOT increment the Integer object  10 that both x and y refer to--because Integer objects are immutable.

Here is another example:

```
x = 10
y = x

x.next
puts x,y  #=> ??
```

x.next creates a new Integer object 11, and because the newly created Integer object 11 is not assigned to a variable, 11 is discarded, so x and y still refer to the same Integer object 10.

Comment: Perhaps `p x.name.object_id` would also help?

Comment: Or don't use "next!", because the exclamation mark is telling you that it can be dangerous.

Comment: ...e.g.  `@@current_name = @@current_name.next`

Comment: That debug code is perfect for showing what is happening. And it will help me get the test to pass so I will mark this as the right answer, but I would still have liked to know if there is a term for this.

Comment: @dewet, It's called `the assignment operator`. I'll add an ascii drawing to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @dewet, I would add: that is how the `assignment operator` works with `mutable` types.  With `immutable` types that doesn't happen.  See the bottom of my answer for an example.

Comment: @7stud that ascii drawing makes it 100% clear what the `assignment operator` is doing here, after it clicked I understand your words that were clearly stating it in the first place when you wrote `each instance's instance variable refers to the same String`